# End-date greater than start-date validation javascript not working properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, unobtrusive-javascript

I am trying to make a validation for my dates so that enddate to be greater than start date but is not working.What am i doing wrong?

```
 <head>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />       
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.19.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>   
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.unobtrusive-0.5.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/gen_validatorv4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

  </head>
     @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchFree", "Reservation", FormMethod.Get,new {id = "form" }))
   {                    

  <h7>Introduceti perioada Rezervarii</h7>
<div class="editor-label">
<label id="cautare" for="StartDate">Data Intrare:   </label>@(Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("StartDate").DateFormat("mm-dd-yy").MinDate(DateTime.Today).ShowButtonPanel(true).ChangeYear(true).ChangeMonth(true).NumberOfMonths(2))
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
<label  id="cautare"  for="EndDate">Data Iesire:</label>@(Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("EndDate").DateFormat("mm-dd-yy").MinDate(DateTime.Today).ShowButtonPanel(true).ChangeYear(true).ChangeMonth(true).NumberOfMonths(2))

</div>

<p>
    <input id="buton1" type="submit" value="Cauta camere libere" />
</p>

      }
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod("EndDate", function (value, element) {
        var startDate = $('.StartDate').val();
        return Date.parse(startDate) <= Date.parse(value);
    }
      , "* End date must be after start date");
     $('.form').validate();
    });
      </script>
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: I don't get any error it just dont making the validation

Comment: Try the code I posted as an answer and let me know if it works for you... Your current code is probably giving you errors somewhere. To see the error(s) you can debug the jQuery code using Firebug for example: http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThan", 
function(value, element, params) {

    if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {
        return new Date(value) > new Date($(params).val());
    }

    return isNaN(value) && isNaN($(params).val()) 
        || (Number(value) > Number($(params).val())); 
},'Must be greater than {0}.');
```

Use it this way:

```
$(".EndDate").rules('add', { greaterThan: ".StartDate" });
```

**or**

```
$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        EndDate: { greaterThan: ".StartDate" }
    }
});
```